# CSS : put checked icon div on the image div

Tags: html, css

I have certain images and when I click on it then a green checked icon is appearing. but i can't make its position to be proper.

```css
.p-t-md{
padding-top:20px;
}
.p-l-md{
padding-left:20px;
}
.speakers_list {
 width: 605px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 245px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div {
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div .speaker_name {
 color: #999999;
 font-size: 10.61px;
}
.speakers_list .selected_div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: #27c24c;
 border: thin white solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row speakers_list p-t-md p-l-md" >
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
        <div class="selected_div">
            <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="speaker_div">
            <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
            <span> 1 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
        <div class="speaker_div">
            <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
            <span> 2 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the green div to be right top and check mark to be centre of the green div and should be responsive , too.

[image: just like in the image]

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Try giving top and right values to ".speakers_list .selected_div"

Comment: thank you but it is not responsive. When I resize my window then I have 4 image in single row and the checked div is not on the image.  I want it to be responsive.

Comment: add "position: relative;" to ".speakers_list" . I hope this will work

Comment: no.. didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this code:

```css
.p-t-md{
padding-top:20px;
}

.p-l-md{
padding-left:20px;
}


.speakers_list {
 width: 605px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 245px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div {
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div .speaker_name {
 color: #999999;
 font-size: 10.61px;
}

.speakers_list .selected_div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: #27c24c;
 border: thin white solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row speakers_list p-t-md p-l-md" >
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                             <div class="selected_div">
                              <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
                            </div>
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 1 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 2 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                         
                         
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

below is updated snippet

```css
.p-t-md{
padding-top:20px;
}

.p-l-md{
padding-left:20px;
}


.speakers_list {
 width: 605px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 245px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div {
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div .speaker_name {
 color: #999999;
 font-size: 10.61px;
}

.speakers_list .selected_div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: #27c24c;
 border: thin white solid;
  right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row speakers_list p-t-md p-l-md" >
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                            <div class="selected_div">
                              <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 1 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 2 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                         
                         
                        </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it is not responsive. When I resize my window then I have 4 image in single row and the checked div is not on the image.  I want it to be responsive.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Add `right: 0;` to `.speakers_list .selected_div`

```css
.p-t-md{
padding-top:20px;
}

.p-l-md{
padding-left:20px;
}


.speakers_list {
 width: 605px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 245px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div {
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.speakers_list .speaker_div .speaker_name {
 color: #999999;
 font-size: 10.61px;
}

.speakers_list .selected_div {
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: #27c24c;
 border: thin white solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row speakers_list p-t-md p-l-md" >
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                            <div class="selected_div">
                              <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 1 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 2 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                         
                         
                        </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it is not responsive. When I resize my window then I have 4 image in single row and the checked div is not on the image.  I want it to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.p-t-md {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.p-l-md {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.speakers_list {
    width: 605px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 245px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div .speaker_name {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 10.61px;
}
.speakers_list .selected_div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #27c24c;
    border: thin white solid;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row speakers_list p-t-md p-l-md" >
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                            <div class="selected_div">
                              <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 1 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                          <div class="selected_div">
                              <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 2 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                          <div class="selected_div">
                              <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 3 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
                          <div class="selected_div">
                              <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_div">
                                <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
                              <span> 4 </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                         
                         
                        </div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: still it is not responsive. you can check by putting `col-sm-4` instead of `col-sm-2`.

Answer (score 0):

Look this

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row speakers_list p-t-md p-l-md" >
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
        <div class="speaker_div">
            <div class="selected_div">
                <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
            </div>
            <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
            <span> 1 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
        <div class="speaker_div">
            <div class="selected_div">
                <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
            </div>
            <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
            <span> 2 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
        <div class="speaker_div">
            <div class="selected_div">
                <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
            </div>
            <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
            <span> 2 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 m-b-lg">
        <div class="speaker_div">
            <div class="selected_div">
                <i class="fa fa-check text-white"></i>
            </div>
            <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2011/02/231256,xcitefun-beautiful-small-nature-world-01.jpg" class=" img-responsive img-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="speaker_name text-center m-t-xs">
            <span> 2 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


</div>

.p-t-md{
padding-top:20px;
}
.p-l-md{
padding-left:20px;
}
.speakers_list {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 245px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.speakers_list .speaker_div .speaker_name {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 10.61px;
}
.speakers_list .selected_div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background: #27c24c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: thin white solid;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Live Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/qn3jyhbb/